# Ruby on Rails / Ruby: Populating Database With Usernames In A File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create users by populating the database with names in a file called **names.rb** which lives in the same place as **seeds.rb**. I am a ruby on rails / ruby newbie so please forgive me if this seems like a simple task. I keep getting the error: Cannot Load File names.rb. I am trying to do this by reading each line in the names.rb file and passing the content to the reiteration block (see below). How do I make sure that each line, for example John Kanye, Matthew Richards, etc. creates a new user with that name? Any help would be appreciated.

**seeds.rb**

```
 require "names.rb"  

 File.open("names.rb").each { |line| puts line }
 Name = line

 User.create!(name:  "Michael Princeton",
                 email: "michaelprinceton@gmail.com",
                 password:              "foobar",
                 password_confirmation: "foobar",
                 admin: true)

    5.times do |n|
      name  = Name
      email = "example-#{n+1}@example.org"
      password = "password"
      User.create!(name:  name,
                   email: email,
                   password:              password,
                   password_confirmation: password)
 end
```

**names.rb**

```
John Kanye 
Matthew Richards 
Mary Mary
Mike Jacobs 
etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename the file to `names.txt`, since it is not Ruby code. Then do something like this:

```
User.create!(
  name:  "Michael Princeton",
  email: "michaelprinceton@gmail.com",
  password:              "foobar",
  password_confirmation: "foobar",
  admin: true
)

File.foreach('db/names.txt').with_index do |name, line_number|
  User.create!(
    name: name,
    email: "example-#{line_number+1}@example.org",
    password: 'foobar',
    password_confirmation: 'foobar'
  )
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did: bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset and bundle exec rake db:seed and got the error, "Errno::ENOENT: No Such file or directory - names.txt". names.txt lives in the same place as seeds.rb. Specifically: appname/db/names.txt. Seeds file lives at appname/db/seeds.rb. Do you by any chance know what is going on here? Thank you in advance and thanks for answering my previous question.

Comment: Usually your run rake taks from the root of your app. So the paht to the file is `db/names.txt`, not just `names.txt`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's a number of problems. It's clear you don't have a firm grasp ruby yet. I highly suggest you find a tutorial or book that starts from the very beginning. That said ..

The `names.rb` doesn't contain ruby code, it's a text file. The file extension `.txt`is used for plain text, so rename the file to `names.txt`.

It doesn't make sense to require a text file. When you `require` a ruby file, it interprets and runs the code in that file. `names.txt` does not contain ruby code. The fix is to delete that line.

Next, it reads the lines one at a time, and prints to standard output. Then the code attempts to set the constant `Name` to the block variable `line` which is now out of scope. It proceeds to create an admin user and five other users in a loop. None of this code accomplishes your goal, so you prolly copy/pasted it from somewhere without understanding it. We've come full-circle to my suggestion to invest time in learning ruby.

What you are looking for is something like:

```
File.open('names.txt').each_line do |line|
  User.create(name: line.strip)
end
```

Learning by doing is wonderful, but you should start with a solid basis.